# Run this script (outlook VBA)on a button and get it to insert in the next line?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

A few months I had a lot of help to write this script. It reads the incoming email and, if the subject is equal to the "Report of Property", it reads the email and opens a file and inserts the values. 
This is what's happening:

1. It opens the file and inserts the values in the correct colums.

What it isn't doing:

1. I want it to find the first empty line in the spreadsheet and paste the values there.
2. I want it to save and close the spread sheet when it's done.
3. Because of the number of emails I'm getting, i would like to know how to run this on a button instead of it reading all emails that come in. Example: I would create a rule in Outlook to move all emails with the specified subject to a folder called "Maintenance Reports". Then, If possible, I would run the macro from that folder and get all the values into the spreadsheet at the end on the day. Is this difficult to accomplish?

Here is the script or VBA code:

```
 Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim id As Variant
Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
Dim msgText As Variant

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


For Each id In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")

Set email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(id)

If email.Subject = "Report of Property" Then
Dim line As Variant

    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\George\Desktop\gs.xlsx", AddTOMRU:=False, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)
   line = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Offset(1).Row


   For Each line In Split(email.Body, vbCrLf)
        If Left(line, 5) = "Name:" Then
             xlSheet.Range("B6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
         ElseIf Left(line, 12) = "Time started" Then
             xlSheet.Range("A6").Value = DateValue(Trim(Mid(line, 14)))
          ElseIf Left(line, 8) = "Sage nº:" Then
             xlSheet.Range("D6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 9))
          ElseIf Left(line, 19) = "Complete Checklist:" Then
             xlSheet.Range("F6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 20))
         ElseIf Left(line, 4) = "Job:" Then
             xlSheet.Range("G6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
          ElseIf Left(line, 9) = "Materials" Then
             xlSheet.Range("W6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 13))
          ElseIf Left(line, 8) = "Duration" Then
             xlSheet.Range("K6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 12))



         End If
    Next


Else:

End If

xlApp.Visible = True

Next
End Sub
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance!
George

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: This is how far I got with trial and error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what's the problem with your current code? Please edit your question to clarify this. If you want someone to help, then please don't keep us guessing.

Comment: Ok. I have created the rule to move the emails to the specified folder "maintenance reports". Now i want to run this script in that folder.  I know how to create the button and how to assing the macro. The only problem I'm having so far is how to get the vba to recognize the emails recieved today in that folder. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, despite the negative rating, I managed to get this to work following  Jean-François Corbett advice. But to be true, I didnt ask the question because I wanted a solution. I askedthe question because i wanted some instruction how to get there. Here is the answer for anyone who would like to try:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Export()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim id As Variant
    Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim msgText As Variant
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")



    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\gsmaster.xlsm", AddTOMRU:=True, UpdateLinks:=True)

    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets("LLCHARGES")



    Dim LR As Long

    LR = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


    Set email = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)
    If email.Subject = "Report of Property" Then

    Dim line As Variant



    For Each line In Split(email.Body, vbCrLf)


    If Left(line, 4) = "Date" Then
    xlSheet.Range("A" & LR).Value = DateValue(Trim(Mid(line, 6)))
    ElseIf Left(line, 5) = "Name:" Then
    xlSheet.Range("B" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
    ElseIf Left(line, 8) = "Sage nº:" Then
    xlSheet.Range("D" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 9))
    ElseIf Left(line, 19) = "Complete Checklist:" Then
    xlSheet.Range("V" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 20))
    ElseIf Left(line, 4) = "Job:" Then
    xlSheet.Range("G" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 5))
    ElseIf Left(line, 9) = "Materials" Then
    xlSheet.Range("W" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 13))
    ElseIf Left(line, 8) = "Duration" Then
    xlSheet.Range("X" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 12))

    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Else

    End If



    Next



    Set xlApp = Nothing

    MsgBox ("Exporting Finished!")
    Else
    MsgBox "Not report email!"
    End If

    End Sub

    Sub Issue()
    Dim xlApp2 As Excel.Application

    Dim xlWB2 As Excel.Workbook

    Dim xlSheet2 As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim id As Variant
    Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim msgText As Variant
    Set xlApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")



    Set xlWB2 = xlApp2.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Work.xlsm", AddTOMRU:=True, UpdateLinks:=True)

    Set xlSheet2 = xlWB2.Worksheets("issues")



    Dim LR As Long

    LR = xlSheet2.Range("A" & xlSheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


    Set email = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)

    Dim line As Variant



    For Each line In Split(email.Body, vbCrLf)



    If Left(line, 12) = "Unrepairable" Then
    MsgBox "Issue found!"
    xlSheet2.Range("C" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 28))
    ElseIf Left(line, 8) = "Sage nº:" Then
    xlSheet2.Range("A" & LR).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 9))
    ElseIf Left(line, 5) = "Date:" Then
    xlSheet2.Range("D" & LR).Value = DateValue(Trim(Mid(line, 6)))

    Else
    If Left(line, 15) = "No unrepairable" Then
    MsgBox "No Issues found!"
    End If

    End If


    Next
    xlWB2.Close SaveChanges:=True
    xlApp2.Quit
    Set xlApp2 = Nothing
    Beep

    MsgBox "Document has been processed!"
    End Sub
```

Then I just created a button on the ribbon that would run the macros in turn. Solved with patience, trial and error.

I post the answer to help other people, like me, who are getting started and need some guidance. 
To those who helped: Thank you! To those who didn't: Thank you too! For the incredibly smart who think that everyone is born smart, that each individual must express himself in binary so that you may understand, i say: .....!

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the Outlook related part of your questions:

> Because of the number of emails I'm getting, i would like to know how to run this on a button instead of it reading all emails that come in. Example: I would create a rule in Outlook to move all emails with the specified subject to a folder called "Maintenance Reports". Then, If possible, I would run the macro from that folder and get all the values into the spreadsheet at the end on the day. Is this difficult to accomplish?

Of course, creating a new instance of the Excel Application class in the NewMailEx event handler is not the right idea.

Also Outlook doesn't provide any way for customizing the UI using VBA. You need to develop an Outlook add-in instead. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) for more information.

You can use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods to find all items in the folder that correspond to your criteria. See the following articles for more information and sample code:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I found some of the answers with what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to check each line in the worksheet for a blank value. Then if it's blank fill that row. Like so:

   Dim blankLine As Long
   blankLine = 2 'or wherever you want to start
   Do
      If xlSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "" Then
         Exit Do
      End If
      blankLine = blankLine + 1
   Loop

You'll then want to use `blankLine` in each statement where your filling in a value on the spreadsheet. For example, `xlSheet.Cells(2, blankLine).Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))`.

2. To save and close the workbook, call the `.Save` and `.Close` methods on the workbook. Example, `xlWB.Save`.
3. There are many good examples of how to add a custom button to the ribbon on MSDN. Try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705%28v=office.14%29.aspx. Search around. There's lots of tutorials out there. Essentially you'll want to wrap what you currently have inside some code that will let you loop through all the messages in a particular folder. Outlook exposes its object model for that. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx.

Good luck!

Comment: There is no way to customize the Ribbon UI from VBA in Outlook! Only the QAT can be customized and then a VBA macro can be assigned.

Comment: In Outlook 2010 you can add custom buttons to the ribbon by using the Customize Ribbon interface (found in Outlook options). From there you can add Outlook VBA macros to ribbons, or groups (or even create your own). You can even give them icons, and custom names. So, while you're right that you can't achieve the end goal from code, it's possible to do what needs to be done by using built-in Outlook features.

Comment: The current web site is for developers. It is expected to see programming questions, i.e. how to do the job programmatically. So, using VBA there is no way to customize the Ribbon UI.